# OpenLayers and React - When using on click, values used inside the function don't update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openlayers

I have a question regarding OpenLayers and React.

Problem: I have a map component that receives an `onClick` function which I'm assigning when I initialize the map. My problem is that if the values used inside the function changes, I still get the one without changes.

CodeSandBox: [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/open-layer-onclick-do1yh?file=/src/App.js)
In the sandbox you will find the map component with an `onClick` that gets assign to the map.
In the `App.js` there is an `onClick` function with a value that after 3 seconds of the first render, it changes from false to true. When doing the click on the map, it stills shows false after the change

Comment: Seems like classic case of stale callback enclosure. What are you trying to do with the `v` value in the `onClick` callback? Also, please do try to update your question here with a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the relevant code with issue.